# How to Query Hierarchical Data in SQL and determine height of each user

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, azure-sql-database, hierarchical-data

I have an Azure SQL table containing all the employees in a company. I use the below query to determine the height of each employee:

```
 WITH emp AS (
        SELECT *, 0 AS d
        FROM tableA
        WHERE Email = '<email>'

        UNION ALL

        SELECT e.*, emp.d + 1
        FROM tableA e INNER JOIN emp
        ON e.ManagerId = emp.Id
)
SELECT  max(d)
FROM emp e
```

Is there a more efficient way to determine the height all the employees in the company without recursively running the above query for each employee?

UPDATE:

Here is my table structure:

```
Id        ManagerId          Email
1            -1              CEO
2             1              ABC
3             1              DEF
4             2              PQR
5             2              STU
6             3              EPS
7             3              DMN
```

Comment: we don't know your table's structure. Check hierarchyId in documentation.

Comment: Please take a look at my table structure

Comment: Use an hierarchyId and then you could siply use GetLevel()

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a more efficient way to determine the height all the employees in the company without recursively running the above query for each employee?

You can do it all with a single recursive query if you start with the top-level employees and recurse down their reporting hierarcies, something like:

```
 WITH emp AS (
        SELECT *, 0 AS d
        FROM tableA
        WHERE ManagerId is null

        UNION ALL

        SELECT e.*, emp.d + 1
        FROM tableA e INNER JOIN emp
        ON e.ManagerId = emp.Id
)
SELECT  e.Id, e.ManagerId, max(e.d)  over () - e.d depth
FROM emp e
```

Comment: Thank you! As you see in my code, I need to find out the maximum depth of each employee (which should be the height). I don't see that in your select query. Could you please clarify that?

Comment: What do you mean by “maximum depth”?

Comment: for example, let's say I have a manager (M1) and M1 has a manager (M2). My height will be 0, height of M1 will be 1 and height of M2 will be 2.

Comment: In the example in my question - Ids 4, 5, 6, 7 will have height 0, Ids 2 and 3 will have height 1,  Id 1 will have height 2

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you! There are a large number of top level employees. So, I see timeout error while running this query. Could you please let me know if there is a way to fix that?

Comment: For performance questions describe your dataset size and post your table and index DDL and your acutal execution plan on https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/.  Also I'm still dubious about what you're defining your measure.  What is the "height" of the CEO's assistant, who isn't anyone's manager?